# Suppose you buy 32-bit PC with 512 MB of RAM. What is the 8-hex digit address of the last byte of installed memory?

Tags: hex, byte, digits

I've searched around and found a thread referring to how to convert 32mb, and using the power-of-2 method. But I'm still not finding the correct answer.

I also have another followup question dealing with the similar problem:

Suppose you buy 64-bit PC with 1024 MB of RAM. What is the 16-hex digit address of the last byte of installed memory?

And I just can't seem to wrap my head around how to solve this logically.

Comment: 1kB is 2^10, ^MB is 2^10kB or 2^20. The last byte is 2^20-1, obviously. So mist likely 0xffff. Maybe share your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

I found that 512BM is a total of 29 bits on or 2^29. So in hex that is 1FFF FFFF. 1024 follows the same method so 2^30 which is 1073741823 or 3FFF FFFF converted to hex. Not really sure what it means by the 16-hex digit address since 1024MB is only 8 bits long. Also not sure what the 32 bit and 64 bit PCs have to do with this question.